# Meanjs environment variable best practices for multiple angular sites under nginx

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I am running multiple angular sites under nginx on a single computer.  When I ran one site, setting environment variables was easy.  I just set them in /etc/environment and was done.  But now I have to set them differently for each site.

For example the meanjs code for setting up a mailer is:

```
mailer: {
        from: process.env.MAILER_FROM || 'MAILER_FROM',
        options: {
            service: process.env.MAILER_SERVICE_PROVIDER || 'MAILER_SERVICE_PROVIDER',
        auth: {
            user: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL_ID || 'MAILER_EMAIL_ID',
            pass: process.env.MAILER_PASSWORD || 'MAILER_PASSWORD'
        }
    }
}
```

Do I just set the hard code the values into the js files?  Or is there someplace to store them locally.  Does this pose a security risk?

Thanks!

Comment: I usually use a config.json if the app will be deployed with other apps.

Comment: Interesting.  I should know this, but how and where would you load config.json?  I see lots of examples under node_modules.  Thanks!

Comment: you would just create a file called config.json, then require it. `var config = require('./config.json'); console.log(config.foobar);`

Comment: You'll have to hardcode the values into the config though, but at least you'll be doing it all within one file for each app.

Comment: You can also expand on the concept to have a config.dev.json and a config.prod.json and include either or based on the environment.

Comment: why would this be better than just hard coding it into the supplied config/env/development.js and config/env/production.js files in meanjs?

Comment: It isn't any better or worse, those serve the same purpose.

Comment: Another alternative would be to namespace your environment variables: `process.env.SITEA_MAILER_EMAIL_ID`